# iOS : import .ics files to calendar

Tags: ios, calendar, sharing

I’m ashamed to ask but how do you importe a .ics file info the calendar app ? (iOS16).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I made a shortcut for this: [**Import .ics**](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/d86646c12538487e8d9be27ed05182c6).

The idea is to use a data URI to open the ics with Safari.

[image]

The configuration of shortcut input allows you to run the shortcut from the share sheet in your screenshot, or by running the shortcut from the Shortcuts app and choosing a file from the file picker that appears.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks! This is exactly what I was doing manually. I just updated the icon to a calendar with a plus to make it even more apparent.